# How to set the JQuery FlexSlider height using CSS?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, flexslider

I am not very into CSS and I have the following website that use **BootStrap** CSS framework and **FlexSlider** JQuery plugin to show the upper slideshow: http://onofri.org/WP_BootStrap/

I have the following doubts about how reduce the slide show height: if using FireBug I decrease the value of **max-height** of the **.flex-viewport** height, this one:

```
.flex-viewport {
    max-height: 2000px;
    transition: all 1s ease 0s;
}
```

I obtain that the height of the shown immages area is decreased to the new value (for example 200 px) ok but now I have the problem that the text written on my immages (represent by the span inside the **.flex-caption-text** paragraph) is in a bad position:

```
            <div id="main-slider" class="flexslider">
                <ul class="slides">
                    <li>
                        <img src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/AsperTheme/assets/img/flexslider/flex-1.jpg"/>
                        <div class="flex-caption">
                            <p class="flex-caption-text">
                                <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
                                <br>
                                <span>sit dolor</span>
                                <br>
                                <span>adipiscing elitur</span>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </li>
```

To obtain that the text is in a good position I think that I can decrease the value of top property of the .flex-caption class

.flex-caption {
    position: absolute;
    right: 8%;
    top: 35%;
}

Is it a good solution or can I have some other kind of problems (maybe in browser different from FireFox)?

The other doubts is related to a **FireBug** behavior, infact if I do the following operations:

1) I change the value of max-height in.flex-viewportin in this way:

```
.flex-viewport {
    max-height: 200px;
    transition: all 1s ease 0s;
}
```

As I say the heigh of the slideshow immages area is decreased

2) I highlight the content of a single slide putting the mouse cursor on this html line:

```
<ul class="slides" style="width: 1000%; margin-left: -1288px;">
```

in this case FireBug show me in blue color the height of this area and it seems to me that have the same height of the old container (2000px), why?

Tnx

Andrea

Answer (score 2):

Instead for changing the value of .flex-viewport to max-height: 200px;

Change value of height in **.flexslider .slides img** in **flexslider.css** file
for eg:

```
 .flexslider .slides img {
width: 100%; 
height:200px;
display: block; }
```

it wont affect your text written on my images